# TextField Background image

Tags: css, javafx-2

I am not able to place a background image inside the borders of a javafx textfield. The image appears covering the right side border.

Here is the CSS used:

```
.text-field-calendar {
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1, 2;
    -fx-background-radius: 3, 2, 2;
    -fx-background-image: url("../../images/pick_calender.png");
    -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -fx-background-position: right center;
    -fx-padding: 3 15 3 5;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could give your background an offset to compensate for the overlap

```
-fx-background-position: right 10 center;
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesnt work. It do not recognize the "right 10 center" syntax.